# Merge requireJS files with grunt

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs

I want to combine the js used in a simple requireJS solution.

This is my main.js

```
require.config({
paths: {
    'jquery': 'jquery-2.0.3.min',
    'dataTable': 'jquery.dataTables'    
}
});

define(['jquery','dataTable'], function($) {
'use strict';
$(function () {

    $('.tablesorter').dataTable();
});

});
```

And my gruntFile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
requirejs: {
  production: {
    options: {
      name: "main",
      baseUrl: "",
      mainConfigFile: "main.js",
      out: "optimized.js"
    }
  }
}
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');

grunt.registerTask('default', 'requirejs'); 

};
```

WHen I load optimized.js in the html like this

```
<script  src="optimized.js"></script>
```

I get 
ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Have you included requireJS before optimized.js?

Comment: Like this ? <script src="require.js">
<script src="optimized.js"> The error is gone but $('.tablesorter').dataTable(); is not executing

Comment: Yes... `require` doesn't exist unless you include `require.js`... as to your other problem you should open a different question with more information. Please close your tags like so `<script src="require.js"></script>`.

Comment: But my problem is I want to all js files in a requireJS solution merged so I only have one js file...

Comment: Check out [this working example](https://github.com/bevacqua/buildfirst/tree/latest/ch05/10_requirejs-grunt) for guidance

Answer (score 0):

You must include `require.js` on the page before including `optimized.js`.

Like so:

```
<script src="/path/to/require.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/optimized.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that requireJS only accepts 'main' as the data-main src

So instead of

```
<script data-main="optimized" src="require.js"></script>
```

I got

```
<script data-main="prod/main" src="require.js"></script>
```

And changed the grunt config to

```
  requirejs: {
   production: {
    options: {
     name: "main",
     baseUrl: "",
     mainConfigFile: "main.js",
     out: "prod/main.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You wrote "I found out that requireJS only accepts 'main' as the data-main src". It is not true that RequireJS only accepts "main" for ``data-main``.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments in addition to the question, first I see that George Raith hit on one problem with your code: you needed to include `require.js`.

Then you said that `$('.tablesorter').dataTable()` is not executed. That's because you use `define` rather than `require`. Use this:

```
require(['jquery','dataTable'], function($) {
    'use strict';
    $(function () {
        $('.tablesorter').dataTable();
    });
});
```

A call to `define` only *registers* a module with RequireJS. It does not *execute* a module. So it is not surprising that `$('.tablesorter').dataTable()` would not execute. You have to use the form of `require` that takes a callback to do what you want to do.

As for including RequireJS with your project into a single file, you have to ask for it explicitly. The optimizer's documentation gives this example:

```
node ../../r.js -o baseUrl=. paths.requireLib=../../require name=main include=requireLib out=main-built.js
```

Your configuration (updated from the one in the question) would look something like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    requirejs: {
        production: {
            options: {
                name: "main",
                baseUrl: "",
                mainConfigFile: "main.js",
                paths: {
                    requireLib: <path to require js>
                },
                out: "optimized.js",
                include: "requireLib"
            }
       }
    }
});
```

(I've not run this code, so lookout for typos.) You have to put the path to your `require.js` file for `requireLib`. We have to use `requireLib` as a module name because `require` is reserved. With this kind of configuration, you should be able to load only your `optimized.js` file.

Comment: $('.tablesorter').dataTable() executes fine using define. Just not when merged into one file. When I see the page in safari and chrome there is a quick flick before the dataTables is loaded when using require...

Comment: 1. In this comment, you are contradicting yourself (To wit: "The error is gone but $('.tablesorter').dataTable(); is not executing"). 2. You are talking about a setup which is different than the ``main.js`` which you've shown in your question. In your question, the ``define`` call is not in a separate file. It is in your ``main.js`` which is loaded directly. 3. This scenario you mention here changes absolutely *not-a-thing* to my explanation. It works is only because somewhere you ``require`` the file that has the ``define`` in it. It is``require`` that cause any module's factory to execute.